# I want to vibrate my notification but it not work how can I do this : this is my code

Tags: node.js, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

```js
else if (userPreferences[prayerName] === 1) {
    console.log("vibration work.....")
    notificationPayload = {
        token: fcm_token,
        notification: {
            title: 'Prayer Time Alert',
            body: `It's time for ${prayerName} prayer`,
            android: {
                priority: "high", // Ensure notification wakes up the device
                sound: null,      // Explicitly disable sound
                      
                vibrate_timings: [
                    "0.2s",
                    "0.1s",
                    "0.2s"
                ],
            },
        },
    };
}
```

on 0 it send notification but on 1 I want to vibrate my notification
This is my notification code

```js
if (userPreferences[prayerName] === 0) {
    notificationPayload = {
        token: fcm_token,
        notification: {
            title: 'Prayer Time Alert',
            body: `It's time for ${prayerName} prayer`,
        },
    };
}
```

it's work okay
but vibration part not working

vibration part not working